# Замена значения переменной в js в iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Есть iframe с `src="sub.domain.loc/frame.html"` на странице `domain.loc/main.html`. В данном iframe имеется js код, в котором из родительской страницы требуется поменять значение переменной `var foto_src="sub.domain.loc/img/img1.jpg";`. Как это можно сделать, не редактируя файл frame.html на поддомене и можно ли это сделать вообще?

Comment: Почитай про `window.postMessage`. Наверное оно подойдет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не подойдет - в окне получателе нужна обработка события: `Чтобы получить сообщение, окно должно поставить обработчик на событие onmessage.`

Comment: и в чем проблема собственно? при получении мессаджа сделай  что-то. например в скрипте приемнике изменяй значение на то, что прибыло из адресата

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, проблема в том, что редактирование frame.html на субдомене недопустимо, что я и описал в вопросе. Т.е. я не могу менять исходные html и js в странице получателе.
Сейчас смотрю в сторону `iframe.contentWindow`

Comment: а. прошу прощения.

Comment: нашел пример [тут](https://onmovie.xyz/serial/68-the-expanse-lostfilm.html) iframe плеера подменяется другим плеером с того же хостинга. но js зашифрован, поэтому не могу понять как это сделано (есть подозрения на jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нет проблем с английским, посмотрите тут:

[StackOverflow.com: Cross-Domain iframe communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949764/cross-domain-iframe-communication#1949764)

Там есть несколько решений, возможно вам это поможет.

Или посмотреть в сторону [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

[StackOverflow.com: cross-domain iframe resizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606920/cross-domain-iframe-resizer)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Получаем iframe
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

//Получаем элемент window из iframe
var contentWindow = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);

//Устанавливаем foto_src
contentWindow.foto_src = "foo.bar";
```

Comment: К сожалению данный метод не работает